# What's the js file size limitation of Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, performance, nashorn

From Java 8 , JDK provides a js engine called Nashorn.
Is there any limitation of js file size on Nashorn?
Will the file size impact the performance of the js running on Nashorn?If yes, what's the best file size of js on Nashorn? or any best practices?

Comment: Before you hit any engine limit, you will hit a maintainability limit.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, Actually,I want to know which js size will get the best performance.

Comment: If file size would affect performance, I'd call that a bug.